# "make" utility missing from PATH error while installing Azure-CLI via pip

Tags: python, azure

I am attempting to install Azure-CLI using the pip package manager with the command `python -m pip install azure-cli`. However, I am encountering an error related to the 'make' utility missing from the PATH.

Environment:

- OS: Windows 10
- Python Version: 3.9.0

Error Details:

Here's the part of the error message that seems most relevant:

```
Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
Failed to build cryptography pynacl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: I see you're using python 3.9, but in the official doc of azure-cli, it seems that python 3.9 is not listed as the supported program language. Can you give it a try on python 3.8 or 3.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the official doc of azure-cli for python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/), python 3.9 is not listed as the supported version. So please try in the early version like python 3.8 or 3.7.

[image]